# What is causing 'unicode' object has no attribute 'toordinal' in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I got this error but I don't what causes it. My python code ran in pyspark. The stacktrace is long and i just show some of them. All the stacktrace doesn't show my code in it so I don't know where to look for. What is possible the cause for this error?

```
/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.parquet.

...
File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 172, in toInternal
    return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the code that caused the error?

Comment: You cut off the traceback. Can you please show *more lines of the code*? I can trace this back to a `StructField`. Perhaps the parent lines show where that field is stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific exception is caused by trying to store a `unicode` value in a *date* datatype that is part of a struct. The conversion of the Python type to Spark internal representation expected to be able to call [`date.toordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) method.

Presumably you have a dataframe schema somewhere that consists of a struct type with a date field, and something tried to stuff a string into that.

You can trace this based on the traceback you *do* have. The [Apache Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark) is hosted on GitHub, and your traceback points to the [`pyspark/sql/types.py` file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/types.py). The lines point to the [`StructField.toInternal()` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L435-L436), which delegates to the `self.dataType.toInternal()` method:

```
class StructField(DataType):
    # ...
    def toInternal(self, obj):
        return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
```

which in your traceback ends up at the [`DateType.toInternal()` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L170-L172):

```
class DateType(AtomicType):
    # ...
    def toInternal(self, d):
        if d is not None:
            return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
```

So we know this is about a date field in a struct. The `DateType.fromInternal()` shows you what Python type is produced in the opposite direction:

```
def fromInternal(self, v):
    if v is not None:
        return datetime.date.fromordinal(v + self.EPOCH_ORDINAL)
```

It is safe to assume that `toInternal()` expects the same type when converting in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to figure out my error based on your hint